# How react append div * num?

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
class AddForm extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                asd
            </div>
        );
    }
}

let addComponents = (num) => {
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        return (<AddForm />);
    }
}

<div className="add">{ addComponents(this.state.addNum) }</div>
```

i want append asd * num
but asd is only one

this.state.addNum = 1

how react append asd * num?

Sorry, i am bad at english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `addComponent` returns a single component, while it should actually return an array of components.

```
const addComponents = (num) => {
    let arr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        arr.push(<AddForm />);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your kind answer

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that you want an output something like this..
if num = 3 then the output should be "asd asd asd"

The code for this will be :

```
class AddForm extends Component {
  render() {
    var str = "asd ";
    for(var i=1; i<this.props.num; i++) {
      str = str+ "asd ";
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {str}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

let addComponents = (num) => {
    return (<AddForm num={num} />);
}

<div className="add">{ addComponents(this.state.addNum) }</div>
```

If you are looking for an output something like this.. (asd * 3) if num = 3 then use the below code..

```
class AddForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            asd * {this.props.num}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

let addComponents = (num) => {
    return (<AddForm num={num} />);
}

<div className="add">{ addComponents(this.state.addNum) }</div>
```

In both the cases, you will understand that you need to pass the props to the child element and let the child element decide what it wants to render.

If you want the output something like this..

```
<div>asd</div>
<div>asd</div> 
<div>asd</div>
```

Then the answer posted above by OB3 is correct.